# Drop down menu with input box

Tags: input, drop-down-menu, box

How can I make a drop down option with a input box using css and html like the picture below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are pluggins for your question such as https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap since you can't insert easily images into a select input but you should always show what you have tried in a SO question.

Comment: I need a same box as like the image. But i don't need the flag in dropdown . i will add some number example:: 017 ,

Comment: So you just need a dropdown? Like this? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify as your need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
     <h2>This is what you want </h2>
      <center>
    <select style="height: 36px; border-right: 4px solid; width: 55px; background: transparent;">
    <option value="India">+91</option>
    <option value="India">+92</option>
    <option value="India">+93</option>
    <option value="India">+94</option>
    <option value="India">+01</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="height: 30px; margin-left: -4px; padding-left: 5px;">
    </center>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes .. But friend its not auto adjust in android screen .please help

Comment: you have to use media query or use bootstrap

Comment: I already try bootstrap. But i can't adjusted  input box and drop down in same line .help please

Comment: how small device you are using >

Comment: Input box will auto adjust any device screen...no matter what device a user use friend

Comment: yes it will . are you using less then 320 px width device ? Handle that by yourself using media query in css.

Comment: I using 540x960 px device

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: I done it bro using   media query in css ..thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

I guess then you need a combo box. A simple way to implement it is with the datalist like this:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList">
    <datalist id="exampleList">
        <option value="017">
        <option value="018">
        <option value="019">
    </datalist>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Need drop down with input box

Comment: I changed my answer for a combobox. Is that what you want?

Comment: No dear friend.  please see this picture  http://i.stack.imgur.com/D4pW2.jpg please see this picture

Answer (score 1):

I guess u require the select statement for the drop down

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
     <select id="exampleList">
            <option value="017">017</option>
            <option value="018">018</option>
            <option value="019">019</option>
     </select>    
     </body>
     </html>
```

this will create the dropdown list